# Freeform styling elements

Tags: solspace-freeform

Is it possible to add placeholder text (i.e. placeholder="Your Name") in a Freeform (not Pro) field? And how to style the submit button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `{exp:freeform:form}` tag is a convenient way to render the form's markup - but because you're dealing with `{freeform:field:name}` instead of raw HTML it doesn't give you that much control over the markup.

However there's a trick so that you can add additional attributes to a field in FreeForm. Simply change your field to this `{freeform:field:name attr:placeholder="Your name"}`

To style your submit button you should use CSS. You can easily target it by adding `form:class="submit-form"` to your opening `{exp:freeform:form}` form and targeting the submit button using `.submit-form input[type="submit"] {}` in CSS.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17042201/how-to-style-input-and-submit-button-with-css for more help with the styling.

Answer (score 1):

You can style the submit button by adding a class:

```
{freeform:submit attr:class="button"}
```

(at least, as of 4.2.4)